# Display for loop output in tkinter window

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter

I have this code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('test_loop')
root.geometry('400x400')
text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, width=40, height=25)
text.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='nsew', padx=20)
def show_msg():
    for i in range(10):
        txt = 'This is {} times though the loop.'.format(i)
        text.delete('1.0', 'end')
        text.insert('end', txt)
        root.after(100)

tk.Button(root, text='Run', width=15, command=show_msg).grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

and can't figure out how to make this update window every iteration in loop .

Comment: there are questions on this site that are very similar, and have answers. Have you done any research?

Comment: remove the `for` loop, add a counter as an argument to the function (`def show_msg(i=1)`), then schedule it with the `.after`: `root.after(1000, show_msg, i + 1)`; add a check to the start of the function: `if counter > 10: return`